# How to use a blob image retrieved from sqlite database

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, opencv, blob

I hope somebody can help me with this problem as I am new to opencv as well as sqlite database. I have got problem regarding my code on how to use the blob image from sqlite database to recognize face using template matching. I have successfully store the image into dbase using blob- from mat image:

```
  QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Image"), "C://Users//yana//Desktop//Detected Faces//",tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)"));
  tpl = cv::imread(fileName.toLatin1().data());
  QImage TImg(fileName);
 // load image to bytearray
 QFile f(fileName);
 if(f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
 {
 ba = f.readAll();
 f.close();
 }
```

So here is where the problem starts. So in order to recognize face, I used cv mat image - `cv:: Mat tpl`. I have retrieve the image from database and convert it to mat image but it did not work. When I did the face recognition, the program suddenly crashed and got error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((img.depth() == CV_8U || img.depth() == CV_32F) && img.type() == templ.type()) in cv::matchTemplate
```

This is my code for retrieving blob image from database and convert it to mat image:

```
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("SELECT TImg FROM TemplateInfo WHERE FaceID='"+Faceid+"'");
    qry.exec();
    qry.next();
    QByteArray ba1 = qry.value(5).toByteArray();
    QImage img = QImage();
    img.loadFromData(ba1);
    tpl= cv::Mat(img.height(), img.width(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE, (uchar*)img.bits(), img.bytesPerLine());
```

Can anybody please help me solve on how to read blob image from sqlite and convert it to mat to further the face recognition? :( thank you.

Comment: Does your face recognition code work if you don't use the database, but save/load the file on disk?

Comment: qry.value(5)  - the 5 doesn't seem right as you only have one filed in the select statement.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11062145/1329652). The answer there is what you're looking for, hopefully. Let us know.

Comment: @MichaelVincent yup Michael. My face recognition works perfectly, only if I selected the template image and proceed with recognition phase at the same time. If I close the program then restart again and just key in the FaceID, it did not work. There is still error on retrieving blob data from database and use it as template and I dont know how to solve it. Please help me :(

Comment: @KubaOber Thank you for your help. I already went through the duplicate question and tried to change my code. But it still did not work. :( I just want to ask do I still need to use .dump if I use the sqlite Manager on firefox Add-on?